# scanning a string using structure

Tags: c

this below is the c code for the structure. in this program while scaning the value of name program is terminating from that point.  and also it takes 2 values as name array. its not giving any runtime error or warning. can u tell me what is the proper solution for this program on my email id `....`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float per;
} st;
main()
{
    clrscr();
    printf("\nenter the info of student");
    printf("\n=======================\n");
    printf("id:");
    scanf("%d:",&st.id);
    printf("name :");
    scanf("%s :",st.name);
    printf("per :");
    scanf("%f :",&st.per);

    printf("\n id is: %d \n",st.id )  ;
    printf("\n name is: %s \n",st.name )  ;
    printf("\n per is: %1f \n",st.per )  ;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a QA site; "please answer quick" and email ids are not useful

Comment: Please provide the length of the name you are trying to enter. Is it more than 19 characters? Please consider rewriting your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d:",&st.id); scanf("%s :",st.name); scanf("%f :",&st.per);
```

Any reason you include the `:` and `whitespaces` in the format string?

Read here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Try all of them again but without the `:`. Eg. `scanf("%d",&st.id);`

Keep in mind that `scanf("%s",st.name);` can end up overwriting memory it should not.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking the return status from the `scanf()` calls, so you can tell which one is failing.

- Are you remembering to add the colons to the input data that your format strings require?

Remember, anything that isn't white space or a conversion specifier in a `scanf()` format is expected in the input, and you are seeking colons after numbers and names.

Also, if you plan to enter both first and last name, the `%s` specifier is not appropriate; it stops at the first space.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
scanf("%s",st.name);
```

When enter the name do not use spaces.
to get the name with spaces use fgets(..)

Comment: The ampersand is not necessary.